# How to get notification for updated IP in grafana datasource?

Tags: performance, monitoring, prometheus, grafana

I am using prometheus as datasource for the grafana dashboard. I am adding the Mesh IP as the URL of the default datasource. Whenever the grafana runs, it creates `grafana.db` which contains all the information related to datasource. I need to work in such a way that user can change the default URL of the datasource. Till now, everything works very well.

Now my problem is, when I try to change the IP of default datasource, and when I run the container again, it again picks the default URL instead of last saved URL in the `grafana.db` file.  I want it to work in such a way that it should read default datasource IP from `grafana.db` if the file is available otherwise read it from default Mesh IP.

I can think of two different approaches for this:

1. Calling some queries using Postgres.
2. Get notified from GUI whenever URL is changed by the user and update that URL in the variable.

I am completely lost how to solve this problem. Anyone please help me how I can solve this problem using above mentioned approaches or any other one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The grafana.db resorts to the old default URL because the data is not being persisted across restarts.

For data persistence, you need to map Grafana to an external DB. Install another db outside docker and use the following link to map it to Grafana: [database_configuration](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/configuration/#database)

Also look at [provisioning](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/provisioning/#data-sources)